# How to set an added row as dirty in Angular UI-Grid

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

There are lots of ways to set a row dirty on edit. I need to set the row dirty on adding it to the grid. Here is what I have so far:

```
$scope.gridOptions.data.push(someNewRow); //this new row is imported from some external source
```

One option would be to use a function in rowEdit to set a row dirty, but it requires a rowEntity object. I could do this:

```
var newRowsEntityObject = ____? // I would need this
$scope.gridApi.rowEdit.setRowsDirty([newRowsEntityObject]);
```

But I need to get a rowEntity object for the new row I'm adding. Other thoughts to get it to work are welcome if my initial direction will not work.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, shoot. Didn't read the documentation clearly for setRowsDirty:

> [N]ote that if you have only just inserted the rows into your data you will need to wait for a $digest cycle before the gridRows are present - so often you would wrap this call in a $interval or $timeout

So I did:

```
$interval(function () {
    $scope.gridApi.rowEdit.setRowsDirty(myNewRows);
}, 0, 1);
```

and it worked fine as they suggested...